# How do I alternate display of 2 elements continuously in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, loops, continuous

I have two image elements:

```
<img src="/image1.gif" id="id1" /><img src="/image2.gif" id="id2" />
```

I'm trying to create a continuous loop in jQuery whereby image1.gif is shown for 1 second, then disappears and image2.gif is shown for 1 second and so on, alternating for N seconds.

I've just about hit a wall with it.

Has anyone got any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To toggle, you can just use [`setInterval()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.setInterval) and [`.toggle()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/) both elements, effectively swapping them, like this:

```
$("#id2").hide(); //start with the frst
setInterval(function() {
  $("#id1, #id2").toggle();
}, 1000);
```

Comment: Holy cow, that was easy. I was looking in completely the wrong direction and had ended up with reams of code. Cheers Nick